# How to insert ESC control characters in a file in FreeBSD?

Tags: shell, sed, freebsd, quoting, escape-characters

I want to enclose Fortran comments with two escape commands (ESC+E and ESC+F).
This implies detecting the comment that begins with `!` until end of line, and prefixing it with `ESC+E` and suffixing it with `ESC+F`.

**First attempt**

```
$ echo "test line  ! Enclose this in ESC commands" | sed 's/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
test line  033E! Enclose this in ESC commands033F
```

The ESC character itself is not generated, instead I get 033.

**Second attempt**

```
$ echo "test line  ! Enclose this in ESC commands" | sed $'s/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
sh: Syntax error: Bad escape sequence
```

**System details**

Operating system: FreeBSD 12.
Shell: [`sh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=&n=1).
Sed: [`sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1).

Comment: If I do `sed 's/\(!.*\)/<ESC>E\1<ESC>F/'  |  sed $'s/<ESC>/\033/g'` then it works, but I  am wondering if I really need two steps, one with `$` and the other one without.

Comment: I don't have FreeBSD OS , but I think this should work: `sed $'/!.*/s//\033E&\033F/'`

Comment: guest_7's suggestion works (tested on a VM running FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p10. works with both /bin/sh and bash), as does `sed $'s/!.*/\033E&\033F/'`.   `sed $'s/!.*/\\\n&/'` works too, and is probably better than using ESC codes - the `\\\n` is because FreeBSD's sed requires a newline in the replacement to be escaped with \ (with gnu sed, you could just use `sed 's/!.*/\n&/'`, without the extra \\ and without $'').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Failed attempts**

There are two levels to understand here. First the shell processes the input,
which is then passed onto Sed.

- ```
   sed 's/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
  ```

  Single quotes preserve the literal meaning of all the characters
  inside, so in this first attempt Sed gets all the characters
  between the quotes.

  However, it fails because Sed does not understand `\033` as the ASCII
  octal 033 (ESC). You may have assumed that,
  but the [Sed manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) says nothing about it.
- ```
   sed $'s/\(!.*\)/\033E\1\033F/'
  ```

  The `$'...'` construct is ANSI C quoting. This is a good idea
  because the shell then transforms `$'\033'` into the ESC character.
  However, [FreeBSD's Sh manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=&n=1)
  contains a list of valid backslash sequences and then clearly says

  > Any other string starting with a backslash is an error.

  Does it list `\(` or `\)`? No, thus the error message. And `\1`, that is
  supposed to go to Sed, would also be interpreted as the ASCII octal 001
  (SOH), which is definitely not what you want.

**Solutions**

Note that for options 1 and 2 below, `\033` can also be written simply as `\e`.

1. Only ANSI quote the `\033` escape sequences, leaving the rest inside normal
   quoting:

   ```
   sed 's/\(!.*\)/'$'\033''E\1'$'\033''F/'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^       ^^^^
                   ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^
   ```
2. No capture group is needed to capture the whole matched string. That is `&` by
   default.

   ```
   sed $'s/!.*/\033E&\033F/'
   ```
3. (POSIX compliant) Use Printf to generate ESC. Choose one of

   ```
   esc=$(printf '\033'); sed "s/!.*/${esc}E&${esc}F/"
   sed "s/!.*/$(printf '\033')E&$(printf '\033')F/"
   ```
4. (POSIX compliant) Awk.

   ```
   awk '{sub(/!.*/, "\033E&\033F"); print}'
   ```